# How to capture screen after some time slot?

Tags: android, eclipse, screenshot

Actually i am trying to capture screen shot from my activity, the code takes the screenshot of current activity but what i need is code has to take the screen shot of the screen after a minute when user clicks the button.

here is my code so:

```
  @Override
      public void run() {
       try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
        takeScreenshot();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) 
        {
      //  Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            takeScreenshot();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

       //   FileTxThread fileTxThread = new FileTxThread(socket);
      //  fileTxThread.start();

        }
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }


    private void takeScreenshot()
{


    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/sna/" + "screenyash"+i + ".jpg";
        i++;
        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

       // openScreenshot(imageFile);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you want to create a Handler and a Runnable, as follow :

```
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Take screenshot();
        }
    };
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
```

And then create a clickListener on your button, launching the runnable to take a screenshot :

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, ONE_MINUTE);
        }
    });
```

Where

```
private final int ONE_MINUTE = 60*1000; //1 minute in milliseconds
```

Hope that helps!